# How to get color of java table row/cell with QTP/UFT (java swing application)?

Tags: java, qtp, hp-uft, vbscript, uft

I need to test that the color of java table row has changed to some specific value. But till now I see no solutions of getting this property.

Let's assume that `jTableObj` is OR or DP representation of `JavaTable` object. So the next code works fine:

```
jTableObj.GetCellData(0,1)    'returns cell data e.g.: <html>Blah-blah...
```

How can I get color of row/cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next code solves the problem:

```
Set cellRender = jTableObj.Object.getCellRenderer(0,1)

' background color '
cellRender.getBackground().toString()
    ' returns: "javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=255,g=255,b=255]" '

' font color '
cellRender.getForeground().toString()
    ' returns: "java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=180]" '

' font name, style, size '
cellRender.getFont().toString()
    ' returns: "java.awt.Font[family=Tahoma,name=Tahoma,style=italic,size=11]" '
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solution lacks a step. After:

```
Set cellRender = jTableObj.Object.getCellRenderer(0,1)
```

There must come:

```
component = jTableObj.Object.prepareRenderer(cellRender, 0, 1)
```

And only then:

```
' background color '
component.getBackground().toString()
' returns: "javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=255,g=255,b=255]" '

' font color '
component.getForeground().toString()
' returns: "java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=180]" '

' font name, style, size '
component.getFont().toString()
' returns: "java.awt.Font[family=Tahoma,name=Tahoma,style=italic,size=11]" '
```

Otherwise you'd get a runtime error